# Upper bound for sum of recipocal primes

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

So I know how to show that $\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{p_k}} \geq \log{\log{n}} - 1$. That can be done using infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p_k}}} \geq H_n$, so $\sum\frac{1}{p_k} + 1 \geq \sum\frac{1}{p_k} + \sum\frac{1}{p_k^2} \geq \sum-\log{(1-\frac{1}{p_k})\geq \log\log{n}}$. Now I would like to show that $\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{p_k}} \leq 2\log{\log{n}} + 4$, but sadly I don't have a clue where to start.